# Data is updating in database but on frontend it is not displayed

Tags: angular, mongodb

i am updating my user details and details are updating but when i refresh my page the old details are showing but data in collection is updated one. when i logout from app and login again then only update information is displayed but it is not displaying on refreshing the component

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  email: string = "";
  firstName: string = "";
  lastName: string = "";
  company: string = "";

  updateUser(): void {
    const userDetails = {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      lastName: this.lastName,
      company: this.company,
      email: this.email,
    };
    this.userService.updateUser(userDetails).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.firstName = response.user.name.first;
        this.lastName = response.user.name.last;
        this.company = response.user.company;
        console.log([this.firstName, this.lastName, this.company]);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

the html component for display

```
<div class="info-details-form">
        <div class="info-form-control">
          <input
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="firstName"
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="firstName"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="info-form-control">
          <input
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="lastName"
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="info-form-control">
          <input
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="company"
            placeholder="company"
            name="company"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="info-form-control">
          <input
            type="text"
            value="{{ email }}"
            placeholder="Email"
            readonly
            name="email"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="info-btn-control">
          <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
          <button class="main-btn" (click)="updateUser()">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

function to update user in backend

```
 public static async updateUser(req, res, next) {
    try {
      const { firstName, lastName, email, company } = req.body.userDetails;
      const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      user.name.first = firstName;
      user.name.last = lastName;
      user.company = company;
      await user.save();
      res.json({
        token: jwt.encode(getJwtPayload(user), UserRoutes.JWT_SECRET),
        user,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include `{new: true}` when updating the document on the `backend`. If you don't include it, document will be updated, but the original one will be returned. You can add it like this:

```
db.collection.update({
  // Filter Query
},
{
  // Update
},
{
  "new": true
})
```

Comment: i have given the function to update user, what am i doing wrong

Comment: Ok, your approach should also work. Can you `console.log()` the result on the frontend and add it to the question.

Comment: in console i am getting updated value of variables and it is also reflecting in input fields but as soon as i refresh old value is displayed in fields

Comment: Are putting data in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` at some point?

Comment: yes my partner is storing in local storage

Comment: That is the problem. When you update the data, you have to update the `localStorage` also.